# React Native posts user's page vs all posts (newsfeed) page

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native, feed, posts

Below is my user's model. Note that `posts` is set as an array. You may ignore everything else, I've only included the rest to eliminate any confusion:

```
User.js

const mongoose =  require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  profilepic: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    // required: true
},
  posts: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
  }
}, { timestamps: true }
)



mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

In MongoDB, the user's post array looks like this, see the `uploadMediaRoutes.js` below if you need a better understanding of the layout:

```
id: "ObjectId(...)"
username: "a username..."
email: "an email..."
password: "a password..."
profilepic: "a profile pic..."
posts: Array
        0: Object
           post: "url here..."
           postdesc: "some text here..."
           likes: Array
           comments: Array
        1: Object...
        2: Object...
        etc....
```

Now, obviously I can get the posts array above to post on an individual user's profile page, showing all of the posts they ever made.

But consider that I had several users and I wanted to post ALL posts, everyone's post arrays submitted into the database, on a type of Social Network "News Feed". Would there be a way to do that given this layout? I realize I could just create a separate Post model, but it'd be super convenient if there were a way to do so by simply taking from all users using the User.js `posts` array.

Below is the backend code, so that you can see how I'm including `likes` and `comments` arrays into the database:

```
uploadMediaRoutes.js

router.post('/posttoprofile', (req, res)=>{
  const { email, post, postdesc } = req.body
 
 
  User.findOne({ email: email })
  .then(( savedUser )=>{
    if(!savedUser){
      return res.status(422).json({ error: "Invalid Credentials" })
    }
    savedUser.posts.push({ post, postdesc, likes: [], comments: []})
    savedUser.save()
    .then(user =>{
      res.json({ message: "Post Added Successfully" })
    })
    .catch( err => {
      res.json({ error: "Error adding post" })
    })
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
 })
```

Here's the front end code in case it will help:

```
postPage.js

const handlePost = ()=>{
      if( post != null ){
        AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
      .then(data =>{
        setLoading2(true)
        fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/posttoprofile', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(data).token
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: JSON.parse(data).user.email,
            postdesc: postdesc,
            post: post
          })
        })
        .then( res => res.json())
        .then( data =>{
          if( data.message == 'Post Added Successfully'){
            alert('Post Added Successfully!')
            setLoading2(false)
            navigation.navigate('Ts_LandingPage')
        } else{
          alert('Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again')
          setLoading2(false)
        }
      })
    })
  } else{
    alert('Please Select An Image')
  }
 }
```

If there's not a way to do what I'm asking (and there very well may not be), feel free to let me know. I just thought I'd ask. Or, if you could point me to an online tutorial, that would work as well. Thanks